# jQuery validation on database-bound dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I am validating dropdown list using jQuery it working fine for normal one:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAreaTypeName" runat="server" Width="163px">
    <asp:ListItem>--SelectOne--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

My jQuery validation is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e) { // <<< This selector needs to point to your form.
        if ($('#ddlAreaTypeName').val() == "") {
            alert("Please select anyone");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Problem is I am binding dropdown from database

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAreaTypeName" runat="server" Width="163px">
</asp:DropDownList>

ddlAreaTypeName.DataSource = ddlValues;
ddlAreaTypeName.DataValueField = "theName";
ddlAreaTypeName.DataTextField = "theName";
ddlAreaTypeName.DataBind();
```

But jQuery validation not working this type of drop down which I am binding from the database.

Comment: When you bind dropdown from data base than already one is selected than whats a problem?

Answer (score 1):

change your code like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myForm').submit(function(e){ // <<< This selector needs to point to your form.

        if ($('#<%= ddlAreaTypeName.ClientID %>').val() == "") {

            alert("Please select anyone");

            e.preventDefault();

            return false;

        }
    });
});
```

if this code does not work , comment me to edit it